# Grant user to read shared calendar using microsft Graph explorer

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I have created a group shared calendar in **Office 365**. All my users are able to read the calendar in their outlook interface but I would like to read this calendar also from an application developed on **Azure**.

When I check with **The Microsoft graph explorer** is some users have access to this shared calendar, an `"access denied is returned".`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "e5a607ba-4885-49ff-b53c-d6df11bc33c0",
            "date": "2019-01-23T10:32:31"
        }
    }
}
```

Which i can play with to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I strongly recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on getting started. Please make sure you include sample code showing how you're retrieving your token and calling the API. Error messages themselves are generally unhelpful without the proper context.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sharing a Calendar to others then you need to set `Calendars.Read.Shared` or `Calendars.ReadWrite.Shared` permissions for Microsoft Graph API to access the shared calendars.  Please refer to the blog [Accessing other mailbox calendars with Graph](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdav_101/2018/06/15/how-to-accessing-other-mailbox-calendars-with-graph/) for more details.
You can also refer to [Microsoft Graph permission names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#microsoft-graph-permission-names) to understand the Microsoft Graph permission patterns.